# Login with username instead of Microsoft account email

Tags: windows, windows-10

How do you login with a username to an account that is associated to a Microsoft account?

Is there a way to work around this without creating a totally separate account?

Just to clarify, the Windows account when created a Microsoft account was used. So what's needed is to be able to login to the same account but not using the Microsoft account.

Answer (score 1):

Here are your optoins:

**Unlink Your account:** You can unlink the Microsoft Account and go back to a local account. I suggest you make sure your User documents and email are backed up. The process works, but I like the security of a good backup.

Here is a decent article to help you:

[Unlink Microsoft Account](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/unlink-microsoft-account/b99b9983-40a9-468e-a15f-3d17a8876ec2)

> Sign into http://account.microsoft.com/devices
>
> Sign in
>
> Under the device, click 'Show details' Click More actions Click Remove
> device

**Make a new Local Account:** You can also, if you wish, back up the documents and email in your account, make a new Local Account, restore your documents and email and then delete the Microsoft Account.

A Local Account is a different type of account from a Microsoft Account. You cannot log into a Microsoft Account with a Local username. You must convert the account.

**Keep the Microsoft Account (good option):** you can just leave the Account as a Microsoft Account. Make sure it has a good password and it is completely secure. I have had a Microsoft Account on this computer for several years and it works very well.

Comment: Is this the only solution? Unlinking the microsoft account would unlike the services, OneDrive etc.

Comment: The solution above is for unlinking the account. You can also back it up, make a new Local Account and restore the date. Then delete the Microsoft Account.

Comment: You can also very safely continue to use a Microsoft Account. They work very well and are safe to use. I added that comment to my answer.

Comment: It really is unnecessary to back user documents.  The process of unlinking and linking a Microsoft Account is relatively seamless, you choose the name of your user profile (i.e. cyberquarks), and a simple logout is all that is necessary.  Your user profile will be renamed to the name of your profile.  This is one foolproof way of changing the name of your user profile if happen to notice it's your Microsoft Account username instead (i.e. quarkscyber).

Comment: I believe @Ramhound to be correct and I clarified my recommendation about backups to indicate this is something I do.

Answer (score 0):

The username for windows accounts with a linked microsoft account is just the first 5 letters of the email.

For example, if the email was `helloworld@outlook.com` the username would be `hello`.

Comment: This isn’t what the author is looking for.  You cannot log into a linked account in this fashion.

Comment: @Ramhound Whenever I log into my shared drives, that is the method I use, and it works fine.

Comment: You use "hello" to log into a local account, that is linked to a Microsoft Account (helloworld@outlook.com), what syntax do you use (i.e. //machinename/hello)?

Comment: @Ramhound anytime i have to enter a username I would just use `hello` nothing extra.

Comment: You saved hours of time